# requestQueue volley doenst work (sending multiple requests)

Tags: android, api, web-services, android-studio, android-volley

I want to upload multiple images (using base64 encode).
I send these images using a for :

```
for(int i =1; i<6; i++){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imgs[i].getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        String image = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bmp);
        SendImage(image);
}
```

But it just send one or two requests of 5 requests! also no error occurs here. I have a requestQueue that I initialized at onCreate method.
And this is my volley request :

```
private void SendImage( final String image) {
    String URL = APPURL;

    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        params.put("image", image);
        return params;
    }
};
{
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this,"added "+requestQueue.getSequenceNumber(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Comment: How do you came to know that? Have you seen `Toast`?

Comment: If you mean error , yes. I removed it here.

Comment: No. I mean how do you came to know that, first two request has been added and not the rest one?

Comment: your question helped me check more and found answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was at the backend part. The images come at the same time and I used time() function to name them so just one or two file saved in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this through the recursion method

like

just you have to call one time

```
multiFileUpload(uploadedFileCount);
```

then it will process all file in recursion model.

```
private int totalFileCount = 6;
private int uploadedFileCount = 1;
private String URL = APPURL;
private multiFileUpload(int _uploadedFileCount)
{
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if((uploadedFileCount<6)
                        {
                           uploadedFileCount++;
                           multiFileUpload(uploadedFileCount);
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imgs[_uploadedFileCount].getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        String image = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bmp);
        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        params.put("image", image);
        return params;
    }
};
{
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this,"added "+requestQueue.getSequenceNumber(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```